# Imports in Processing?

Tags: processing

I have a file system like so:

```
sketch
- sketch.pde
builtins
- button.pde
```

Where `sketch.pde` is my main Processing sketch, and `button.pde` is an external file containing various classes.

How do I access the classes from `button.pde`? I'm guessing it's through an `import` but I don't know if it's different in Processing than in Java.

I tried looking for an answer by looking through various open-source Processing projects, but all of the files were in one place, so no imports were required.

**EDIT:**

Apparently basic importing is impossible in Processing.

I have a mini-question then: I have another file system:

```
sketch
- sketch.pde
- builtins
  - button.pde
```

Can I access `button.pde` now? Or is it still impossible?

Comment: Are you asking about Java or Processing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Processing. TBH, I put the Java tag in mainly because no one would answer if I didn't. I can get rid of it if you want. The languages are similar, anyway.

Comment: see https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/12845/include-in-processing

Comment: To be honest, no one might answer even _with_ the Java tag.  But here, have an upvote.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I looked at it for a while, and apparently there isn't a solution - the devs of Processing said that imports for Processing wasn't going to happen, for some strange reason.

Comment: Could always use Java ;-)

Comment: I think I should just post an issue on the Processing repo, but it'll get closed immediately, probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** [Mitchell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41798175/873165) below shows that this is possible. Go read that answer!

One option is to use [Processing as a Java library](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java). You could then write some code that you export as a `.jar` file, which you could then drag onto your `sketch.pde` Processing editor and import the classes. In other words, you could create your own library that you then use in the Processing editor.

Another low-tech option is to copy the classes you want to use from `button.pde` into new tabs in `sketch.pde`.

Comment: So it's impossible to have multiple folders in a Processing project? That's disappointing.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp Processing was designed to be dead simple. If you need something more complicated, use eclipse.

Comment: I might also have a sub-question. Can I add it on to my original question?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp I don't understand how this is such a deal-breaker. What exactly is your end goal? And if you have a follow-up question, you should probably just post it in its own new question.

Comment: Yeah you're right, it was kind of an exaggeration. I can probably continue, it's just going to be a pain in the butt.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp But no, putting your `.pde` file in a subdirectory doesn't let you import it. It doesn't matter what the `.pde` file is located, this simply isn't a feature in the Processing editor.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp If you really really need something like this for some reason, then you can use Processing, just not the Processing editor. Or you could create a library that you import into Processing like I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp Also note that you can use tabs within the Processing editor. Just create a new tab and put your code there. Then go back to your main tab and put your main code there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133400/discussion-between-qwerp-derp-and-kevin-workman).

Answer (score 5):

You *can* access the classes in button.pde by simply placing button.pde in the same folder as sketch.pde.

For example, let's say button.pde contains a class called RedButton. As long as you have a folder called sketch/ with sketch.pde and button.pde inside it, you can say `RedButton rb = new RedButton();` in sketch.pde and you will have created a new instance of the RedButton class.

Are you using the Processing IDE or are you using the command line tool to launch your project? If you are using the IDE, you will just want to see that sketch.pde and button.pde are visible as tabs in the same project when you open it. Hope this helps!